FlaskForm does not validate
I need help with my Flask app. I have page with FlaskForm which calculates profit from selling a product. The idea is that if page is loaded directly or by link data for calculations is obtained from database. But then user can change some values in FlaskForm and submit it to get new calculations. And when page is loaded after submiting the form part of the data must be obtained from the form.
Here is my code for URL processing of this page:
@app.route('/ozon-unit-economy', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ozonUnitEconomy():
    ozonProductId = request.args.get('id')
    productData = dict()

    form = ozonUnitEcForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        productData = func.loadOzonProdUEData(form, None, ozonProductId)
        calcResults, miscData, currentDate = func.calcOzonUnitEconomy(productData, form.date.data)
    else:
        productData = func.loadOzonProdUEData(None, None, ozonProductId)
        calcResults, miscData, currentDate = func.calcOzonUnitEconomy(productData, date.today())
        
    form.date.data = currentDate    
    form.price.data = productData['price']
    form.salePrice.data = productData['salePrice']
    form.purchasePrice.data = productData['purchasePrice']
    form.purchaseDiscount.data = productData['purchaseDiscount']
    form.factoring.data = productData['factoring']
    form.factoringComRate.data = productData['factoringComRate']
    form.fastMoney.data = productData['fastMoney']
    form.payDelay.data = db.session.execute(
        db.select(ozonPayDelay).filter_by(delay=productData['payDelay'])
        ).scalars().first()
    form.crr.data = productData['crr']
    form.sellerInst.data = productData['sellerInstComRate']
    form.sellerBonusRate.data = productData['sellerBonusRate']
    form.fboExp.data = productData['fboExp']
    form.fbsExp.data = productData['fbsExp']
    form.realFbsExp.data = productData['realFbsExp']
    form.fboWarehouseFrom.data = db.session.execute(
        db.select(ozonWarehouse).filter_by(id=productData['fboWarehouseFrom'])
        ).scalars().first()
    form.fboWarehouseTo.data = db.session.execute(
        db.select(ozonWarehouse).filter_by(id=productData['fboWarehouseTo'])
        ).scalars().first()
    form.fboCrossDockPackage.data = db.session.execute(
        db.select(ozonCrossDockingPackage).filter_by(key=productData['fboCrossDockPackageKey'])
        ).scalars().first()
    form.fboTurnover.data = productData['turnoverFbo']
    form.fboLocalIndex.data = productData['fboLocalIndex']
    form.fbsDropOffCost.data = productData['dropOffCost']
    form.realFbsCost.data = productData['realFbsCost']
    form.realFbsComp.data = productData['realFbsComp']
    form.fboReturnRate.data = productData['returnRateFbo']
    form.fbsReturnRate.data = productData['returnRateFbs']
    form.realFbsReturnRate.data = productData['returnRateRealFbs']
    form.fboReturnExp.data = productData['expReturnFbo']
    form.fbsReturnExp.data = productData['expReturnFbs']
    form.realFbsReturnExp.data = productData['expReturnRealFbs']

    return render_template('ozon-unit-economy.html', title='Юнит-экономика товара Ozon', form=form, productData = productData, miscData = miscData, calcResults = calcResults)

And here is the form:
class ozonUnitEcForm(FlaskForm):
    date = DateField('Дата', validators=[DataRequired()])
    price = IntegerField('Цена (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1)])
    salePrice = IntegerField('Цена по акции (р.)', validators=[NumberRange(min=1)])
    purchasePrice = DecimalField('Закупочная цена (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0.01)])
    purchaseDiscount = DecimalField('Скидка поставщика (%)', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=99.99)])
    factoring = BooleanField('Факторинг')
    factoringComRate = DecimalField('Комиссия за факторинг (%)', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=99.99)])
    fastMoney = BooleanField('Гибкий график выплат')
    payDelay = QuerySelectField('Отсрочка выплат', 
                query_factory=lambda: db.session.execute(
                db.select(ozonPayDelay)).scalars(), 
                get_label='delay')
    crr = DecimalField('ДРР (%)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=99.99)])
    sellerInst = BooleanField('Рассрочка продавца')
    sellerBonusRate = IntegerField('Бонусы продавца (%)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1)])
    fboExp = IntegerField('Стоимость упаковки FBO (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    fbsExp = IntegerField('Стоимость упаковки FBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    realFbsExp = IntegerField('Стоимость упаковки realFBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    fboWarehouseFrom = QuerySelectField('Склад отправки партии товара', 
                query_factory=lambda: db.session.execute(
                db.select(ozonWarehouse)).scalars(), 
                get_label='name')
    fboWarehouseTo = QuerySelectField('Склад доставки партии товара', 
                query_factory=lambda: db.session.execute(
                db.select(ozonWarehouse)).scalars(), 
                get_label='name')
    fboCrossDockPackage = QuerySelectField('Упаковка для кросс-докинга', 
                query_factory=lambda: db.session.execute(
                db.select(ozonCrossDockingPackage)).scalars(), 
                get_label='name')
    fboTurnover = IntegerField('Оборачиваемость на складах OZON (дн.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    fboLocalIndex = IntegerField('Индекс локализации (%)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=99)])
    fbsDropOffCost = IntegerField('Стоимость обработки отправления FBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    realFbsCost = IntegerField('Стоимость доставки на realFBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    realFbsComp = IntegerField('Компенсация доставки на realFBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    fboReturnRate = DecimalField('Процент возвратов FBO (%)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=99.99)])
    fbsReturnRate = DecimalField('Процент возвратов FBS (%)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=99.99)])
    realFbsReturnRate = DecimalField('Процент возвратов realFBS (%)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=99.99)])
    fboReturnExp = IntegerField('Стоимость обработки возврата FBO (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    fbsReturnExp = IntegerField('Стоимость обработки возврата FBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    realFbsReturnExp = IntegerField('Стоимость обработки возврата realFBS (р.)', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0)])
    submit = SubmitField('Рассчитать')

And here is the screenshot of the page: page wish FlaskForm
My idea is that if form validates on submit than the form is passed to the function 'loadOzonProdUEData' to obtain part of necessary data from the form. And if it is not form is not passed and then function 'loadOzonProdUEData' loads all the data from database.
The problem is that form never validates on submit and I do not know why. Also I think this might be not a good idea because when form does not validate in case something is wrong with it the calculation will still be processed with data form database but it is better to get an error message in this case to correct what is wrong.
Please advice the better way to do what I need.
